# Dynamics 365 Case Status optionset value

Tags: dynamics-crm

**Hi People, I've a requirement for Dynamics 365 Case Status optionset value [enter image description here][1]along with case stage i.e. Stage : Open, Case status Options :1,3 ; Stage: Research Options :3,4,5. the problem is the status options aren't changing when select the next/previous  Case Stage.**

```
            function onCaseStageChange(executionContext) {
            debugger;
            if (executionContext != null) {
                var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

                // setOptionSet(formContext);

                formContext.data.process.addOnStageChange(stageselected(formContext));
                formContext.data.process.addOnStageChange(stagechange(formContext));
            }
        }

        function stagechange(formContext) {
            debugger;
            var activeProcess = formContext.data.process.getActiveProcess();

            if (activeProcess != null && activeProcess != undefined) {

                if (
                    formContext.data.process.moveNext(function (result) {
                        if (result == "success") {
                            var currentstageId = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getId();
                            var currentStageName = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getName();
                            //formContext.data.entity.save();
                            //formContext.data.process.setStatus("active");
                            // // formContext.data.entity.save();
                            // Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());


                            setOptionSet(formContext);


                        }

                    }));

                if (

                    formContext.data.process.movePrevious(function (result) {
                        if (result == "success") {

                            var currentstageId = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getId();
                            var currentStageName = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getName();
                            //  formContext.data.entity.save();
                            //formContext.data.process.setStatus("active");
                            //formContext.data.entity.save();
                            //Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
                            setOptionSet(formContext);

                        }

                    }));

            }

            return activeProcess;
        }




        function setOptionSet(formContext) {
            var stageName = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getName();
            if (stageName == "Open") {
                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 1, text: 'In Progress' });
            }

            if (stageName == "Identify") {


                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 3, text: 'Awaiting Information' });

            }
            if (stageName == "Research") {
                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640000, text: 'Awaiting Inspection' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640001, text: 'Technician Appointed' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640002, text: 'Awaiting Technician Report (Visit 1)' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640003, text: 'Awaiting Technician Report (Visit 2)' });
            }
            if (stageName == "Resolve") {
                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 2, text: 'Awaiting Parts' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640004, text: 'Awaiting Repair' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640005, text: 'Awaiting Repair (Tech Visit)' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640006, text: 'Awaiting Replacement' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640008, text: 'Awaiting Collection' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640009, text: 'Return' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640010, text: 'Awaiting Decision' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640011, text: 'Escalation' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 4, text: 'Awaiting Credit/Debit' });
            }
            if (stageName == "Closed") {
                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 5, text: 'Awaiting Final Costs' });
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 1000, text: 'Pending Recharge to Supplier' });
            }
            if (stageName == "Archived") {
                var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
                newStatus.clearOptions();
                newStatus.addOption({ value: 979640007, text: 'All Actions Completed' });
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stageselected(formContext) {

            var stage = formContext.data.process.getSelectedStage();
            var stageId = stage.getId();
            //formContext.data.process.setActiveStage(stageId);
            //formContext.data.entity.save();
            //Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
            setOptionSet(formContext);
            //formContext.data.entity.save();
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After refering to Microsoft Documentation and doing trial and error, Found solution to show/hide header control option set on Case Entity.

1.Create a field on case entity and keep it hidden on Case Entity.
2. Create a Real Time workflow on the Associated BPF Entity(new_bpf_UniqueID)
[Options for automatic process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stdh0.png)
3.[update the field from step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lJfC.png)
4. Implement a Jscript for show/hide Optionset control on "OnChange" Event of the hidden field

```
function onCaseStageChange(executionContext) {
debugger;
if (executionContext != null) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var stageName = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getName();
    setOptionSet(formContext, stageName);
    
}
```

}

```
function setOptionSet(formContext,stageName) {

if (stageName == "Open") {
    var newStatus = formContext.getControl("header_process_statuscode");
    newStatus.clearOptions();
    newStatus.addOption({ value: 1, text: 'In Progress' });
}
```

}